# не работает код по указателям из книги С++

Tags: c++

В книге "С++ Базовый курс" Г.Шилдт есть код по указателям, который у меня при компиляции выдает ошибку.
Пользуюсь программой Code Blocks 2009. Возможно ли что причина в этом?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
　char *s;
　s = "Работа с указателями - сплошное удовольствие! \n";
　cout << s;
　return 0;
}
```

Comment: Причина в том, что надо написать `const char * s;`.

Comment: Попробовал  const char *s;. Не помогло.

Comment: Вот - https://ideone.com/0Ppgma - как видите, работает. Смотрите у себя, что не так с вашим текстом. Вы же считаете ниже своего достоинства сообщить, какую именно ошибку выдает компилятор... Может, вы где-то русские символы вместо английских воткнули :)

Comment: Действительно, ошибка была в русских буквах. Скопировал текст с инета. Компилятор выдавал много ошибок какую именно указывать я не знаю. Сильно не ругайтесь.  Я новичок.  Спасибо за ответ. Все заработало.

Comment: Стоит использовать что-нить поновее Code Blocks 2009. Хотя бы Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const auto s = "Работа с указателями - сплошное удовольствие!\n";
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: А где тут указатель?

Comment: @Furious_pawn s

Comment: Разве не должен стоять символ *  ?

Comment: @Furious_pawn нет

Comment: const auto s  - тоже ошибка при компиляции.

Comment: @Furious_pawn нет ошибок https://godbolt.org/z/MKoDFM

Comment: Если полностью ваш код вставить, тогда нет ошибки.

Comment: @Furious_pawn так в чём проблема тогда?

Comment: Простите, а на... вобщем, какой глубокий смысл в `auto`, кроме как новичка окончательно запутать?

Comment: @Harry надо писать `auto` везде, где можно

Comment: Ну-ну, дерзайте... Когда надоест или просто не сможете сопровождать такой код, вспомните меня :) Да, кстати, указатели, наверное, тоже использовать не нужно, есть же `string`...

Comment: @Harry в прикладных программах в современном `C++` почти не надо использовать явно указатели, только в низкоуровневых местах и с `C`-интерфейсами

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: Разве указатели не является исключительной фишкой С++ которая увеличивает быстродействие программы и делает код компактнее?

Comment: @Furious_pawn не является, в других языках тоже есть. А про быстродействие и компактный код надо говорить в конкретной ситуации. В общем случае нет

Comment: Мой - за то, что ТС спросил, как работать с указателями, а у вас он надежно спрятан.

Comment: @Mikhailo он не спрашивал, как работать с указателеми, он написал, что у него ошибка компиляции. Да и вопрос "как работать с указателями" очень широкий для стэка в любом случае